# Why my window postMessage isn't working ? Not using iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've been trying several things in my project to send cross-domain variables.
I have a button that I click, and opens a new browser tab.

```
$('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
 var popup = window.open("other-domain.html", "_blank");
 window.popup.onload = function() {
    popup.postMessage(variableToSend, '*');
 }

 // I even tried doing this directly, without the onload
 popup.postMessage(variableToSend, '*');
});
```

From my other domain I do this:

```
(function($) {
  var listener = function(event) {        
    console.log(event.data);
  }

  var setupEvents = function() {
    if(window.addEventListener) {
      window.addEventListener("message", listener, false);
    }else{
      window.attachEvent("onmessage", listener);
    }
  }

  setupEvents();
})(jQuery);
```

I never receive anything from my parent window, so never gets inside listener function.

Do you know what could be wrong ? Been fighting with this for 2 days already.

Thanks in advance,

ADDED:
I tried doing this from the other domain window (children)

```
window.parent.postMessage('Hi!', '*');
```

And it receives the message correctly. Looks like I'm missing something, maybe a Timeout somewhere?

Comment: popup is a variable in function scope, so window.popup.onload will not address your popup

Comment: Yea, i also tried doing it without the "window", but didn't work... i tried again but i can't make it work.

Comment: Now, if i do this from the children window window.parent.postMessage('Hi!', '*'); it works, listens to the message. What am I missing? a Timeout?

Comment: Does it work if you open the window with a unique id, instead of _blank ?

Comment: Oh, looks like we are getting closer now. With an ID it worked instead of _blank, thing is... the first time i open the new page... it won't receive anything, if i open it once it was opened, i receive it. But then, it will refresh the page and i lose the message. How can i resolve this?? Thanks for replying though :)

Comment: I'm not experienced with the subject hence no answer, but this is something I saw elsewhere (can find the link now though)... maybe you need to add that the window id/name as origin inside postmessage... read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: Here's another reference: http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/dom/Window/postMessage

Comment: Yea i read all those articles, and i'm doing the same thing, but still.. on the 2nd one, is not doing a window open, i believe its in an iframe, with different sources and that's it. There shouldn't be a problem with that, the problem is when i open a new tab/window. And it looks like due to cross-domain issues, i can't find a way to get like an onload event from that popup.

Comment: Dont worry, i spent so many hours on this, i will try to do something else, like passing the variable in the URL... thanks for trying though